# Mapping a triangular matrix to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

The MATLAB function, `pdist`, computes pairwise distances for a set of points.  In order to save space and time, it elides repeat ( `dist(A,B) == dist(B,A)` ) and self ( `dist(A,A) == 0` ) comparisons.  The result is returned in a single vector, with indices `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`.  Expanding into a full distance matrix ( e.g. by the function `squareform` ), the positions are mapped like:

```
-  -  -  -  -
1  -  -  -  -    # "1" is subscript "1,2"
2  5  -  -  -    
3  6  8  -  -    # "6" is subscript "4,2"
4  7  9  10 -
```

Given a vector such as that produced by `pdist`, what is the expression to convert an index into that vector into the subscript indices of the full distance matrix?

For example, I wish to find, in a set of points, the two points most distant from each other:

```
d = pdist(points); %# points is M x 2 (or 3, etc.), d is described above
N = length(d);
[~,I] = max(d); %# I is the index, e.g. 6
CI = ceil( sqrt( 2*N ) ) - round( sqrt( 2*(1 + N - I) ) ); %# Identity of one point, e.g. 4 is I == 6
RI = ????  %# Identity of second point, e.g. 2, if I == 6 and CI == 4
```

As indicated above, I have the first part, to find the first subscript.  I can't quite figure out the second one.  There are a number of related questions (*vide infra*) but the answers aren't correct (or are specific to 0-index, row-major languages).

- [algorithm for index numbers of triangular matrix coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242711/algorithm-for-index-numbers-of-triangular-matrix-coefficients)
- [Mapping elements in 2D upper triangle and lower triangle to linear structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803180/mapping-elements-in-2d-upper-triangle-and-lower-triangle-to-linear-structure)

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, would you be able to rephrase?

Comment: Is it sufficiently explained now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@reve_etrange I believe N should be the length of d, not the number of rows of your points matrix.

```
K=5; % Number of points
d = pdist(rand(K,3));
N = length(d);
m = ceil(sqrt(2*N));
I = 1:N;
CI = m - round( sqrt( 2*(1 + N - I) ) );
RI = mod(I + CI.*(CI+1)/2 - 1, m) + 1;
```

This results in

```
I =    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
RI =   2     3     4     5     3     4     5     4     5     5
CI =   1     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     4
```

Comment: Nope. The expression in my answer works with the number of rows in `points`. Your subs are the same as mine.

Comment: Yep. But I don't have to allocate memory for a N by N matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the question are still nonsense, but I believe this is what you're trying to do...

Find the subscripts of the nonzero elements of a lower triangular matrix that is the same size as your distance matrix:

```
>> points = randn(5,2);
>> [i,j] = find(tril(ones(size(points, 1)), -1))

i =

     2
     3
     4
     5
     3
     4
     5
     4
     5
     5


j =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3
     4
```

Comment: That works, but has to call `find` and `tril` again for every set of points.  The correct algebraic expression will definitely use less space and might be faster.  Also, please explain why my question is "nonsense," so I can fix it.  If you really think the question is irreparable, you should flag it.

Comment: The last sentence could be omitted.